# C# How do i create a reference to a list from another class?

Tags: c#, list

so i have this list of products.

now, what i want to do is loop over this list in another class with a foreach.

how do i make a reference to AllProducts in the class i want to loop in?

```
public List<Product> AllProducts;
AllProducts = new List<Product>();


foreach (product p in AllProducts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A
{
    //Property
    //must be set somewhere (e.g. constructor)
    public List<Product> Products { get; private set; }

    //Method
    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        //return list of products
    }
}

public class B
{
    public void Display()
    {
        var a = new A(); 
        foreach (var product in a.Products /*OR a.GetProducts()*/)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to have *both* the property and the method at the same time? If yes, then that's poor design, violating the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Comment: Of course not, i just put it there to show possible ways to solve this problem. OP should make a decision to use property or method.

Comment: Oh my god thank you! i had completely forgot i had to make a new object in order to get a reference to allproducts! thanks man!

Comment: @Linexxlol No objects would be created. You'll just get the reference to the same list (maybe I misunderstood you).

Answer (score 0):

It'll be better if You create a method in class that have that list and name it something like "showProducts()" and iterate with Console.WriteLine and in Your main class call that method.

Comment: hi! yea okay, i've done that:

public List<Product> GetProducts()
{
return AllProducts;
}

but i still need to iterate over AllProdcuts in main i can't do it in the method for other reasons.

Answer (score -1):

```
public List<Product> fillProduct()
    {
        List<Product> AllProducts = new List<Product>();
        //fill 
    }
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (product p in fillProduct())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
```

> You can do like this